# Homework question, think the textbook might be one in the following trigonometry question

Tags: trigonometry

42.       If $A = \tan^{–1}(-3/4)$ and $A + B = 315°$, then $B = $

(A) 278.13°             (B) 351.87°             (C) –8.13°             (D) 171.87°             (E) 233.13°

Ku, Richard. Barron's SAT Subject Test Math Level 2, 10th edition (Kindle Locations 619-624). Barron's Educational Series. Kindle Edition.

The textbook gives the answer as C, but it could be B or C or D right?

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $$-90^\circ<\tan^{-1}\left(-\dfrac34\right)<0$$

$$\implies B>315^\circ$$

$$\tan B=\tan\left(315^\circ- A\right)=\dfrac{\tan315^\circ-\tan A}{1+\tan315^\circ\tan A}$$

Now $\tan315^\circ=\tan(360-45)^\circ=-\tan45^\circ=-1$

Answer (score 0):

First, find $\angle A = \arctan (-3/4)$, which in this case is $-36.87°$.

We usually go counterclockwise around the unit circle, so we want to keep the angles positive.  Add $360°$ to $-36.87°$ to get $323.13°$.  Since $\angle A + \angle B = 315°$, $\angle B = 315 - 323.13°$ or $-8.13°$, or answer (C).

Each of the other answers are incorrect as follows:

- (A) $-36.87° + 278.13°$ = $241.26° \neq 315°$
- (D) $-36.87° + 171.87° = 135° \neq 315°$
- (E) $-36.87° + 233.13 = 196.26° \neq 315°$

The reason why (B) is not the answer compared to (C), even though we would get the same sum of angles (i.e. $-36.87° + 351.87°$ = $315°$) is we're going counterclockwise around the unit circle; if we went clockwise around the unit circle, then we can consider negative angles and (B) would be fine.  (If I'm not correct on this, please let me know.)